# Change variable in array or list

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change second element in my array using loop in this way:

```
myTab = [false,true,true];

  if (trueOfFalse){
            for (let i = 0; i < myTab.length; i++) {
                myTab[i].set(true)
  }
  myTab[3] = false;
```

How to fix it for running ? In Java this works.

Comment: What are you supposed to do?

Comment: What's exactly the problem with the code ?

Comment: crash, no works

Comment: What do you mean by trueOfFalse? Is it a variable name?

Comment: See [ask]. Tell us what you want to do and provide a [mcve] that shows the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your question doesn't really make sense but here is some JavaScript that will change the second item in the `myTab` array to be `false`. I'm sure you can adapt it how you see fit.

```
const myTab = [false, true, true];

for (let i = 0, len = myTab.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (i === 1) {
        myTab[i] = false;
    }
}

// Log the modified array
console.log(myTab);
```